# Predict parameters in sklearn Pipeline

Tags: scikit-learn, pipeline, predict

I was wondering if it was possible to pass predict arguments into the predict method of a `Pipeline`. For example boosting implementations like XGBoost and LightGBM have a `num_iterations` argument that limits the numbers of tree that are used for prediction. However, the `pipeline.Pipeline`'s `predict` method signature doesn't make it possible to pass so-called `predict_params`.

Is there something I am not seeing?

Kind regards.

Comment: There's an issue at scikit learn github for this exact issue. Please [take a look at it](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/9293).